# Excel 2013 VBA change a chart object source using dynamic range

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I am trying to dynamically set a chart object source. The *fdc* and *ldc* variables will change over time.
I've tried several variations of code; my latest attempt being:

```
fdc = 26
ldc = 90
ws.ChartObjects("Chart 2").SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range("S" & fdc & ":V" & ldc)
```

but they all give:

> Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're referring to the ChartObject.
`SetSourceData` is a method of the `Chart` inside the `ChartObject`.

Try

```
fdc = 26
ldc = 90
ws.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range("S" & fdc & ":V" & ldc)
```

Comment: Excellent. I had read this several times when searching for a solution but I didn't see how to apply it to my situation.

Comment: It did but I had to wait two minutes before I could mark it as an answer.